# Install Django apps through the Django admin-site like plugins in Wordpress

Tags: python, django, module

I want to implement a module-manager in Django where third-party modules can be installed through the django admin interface (without changing the code-base of the main project). Or it could also be a service that runs on top of django.

These modules should have the same capabilities as a django app. For example, defining models and views, making migrations, and interacting with other apps. Similar to how it works with the plugin-manager of Wordpress.

Is there a good way to do this? (and are there reasons why I should not?)

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer if you described in more detail what you are after. For example, I don't know what a "plugin-manager of WordPress" is, so I lack context. When you mention "without changing the code-base of the main project", what do you mean exactly? Pip-installing third-party packages doesn't change the code. Do you need virtual environments to separate your main codebase python setup?

Comment: By "plugin manager of Wordpress" do you mean a UI to install new apps.This is already possible by editing the settings file

Answer (score 2):

What is a Django app? According to [Django Packages](https://djangopackages.org/categories/apps/)

> Small components used to build projects. An app is anything that is installed by placing in settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

---

Generally speaking, here are the steps to have an app working in Django

1. Install the app

   ```
   pip install app
   ```
2. Register the app in one's `settings.py`

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...
       'app',
       ...
   ]
   ```
3. In some cases they'll require to sync the database. Such is the case with [`social-auth-app-django`](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html). Here you'd have to do as well

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   ```
4. In some other cases they require specific versions of Python, Django, ect, so that'd have to be taken in consideration too. Such is the case with Django REST framework which requires

   ```
   Python 3.6+
   Django 4.1, 4.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.0
   ```
5. It's possible as well that apps are dependent on certain Python libraries. Then, one would have to install them too.

---

For a basic version of that, one wants to create a place to have a button to install an app as well as a model to store the app. The model will keeps track of specific variations with [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield).

More precisely, since we now know some apps require database sync, the app model will have `requires_db_sync = BooleanField(default=False)`. Then, if that's true, when installing that app one will want to run at least steps 1, 2 and 3.

---

One will eventually want to do a thorough analysis of the existing apps and understand the different possible variations (dependencies, requiring DB sync, etc).

---

I work with WordPress too and this was a thought that came to my mind a few years ago. I didn't pursue it because for most apps I  still had to go to the code and do various configurations.
To deal with that, WordPress plugins, like [`WPForms`](https://wpforms.com/), come with pages where one does that configuration.
Since such Django app configuration pages for configuration don't yet exist, they'd have to be created as well.
Also, would be great to have a trusted agency with standards to validate an app as good to be in that system.